# Representations of two-dimensional Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

It is widely known that there is only one $2$-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra: it can be generated by two vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ such that $[e_1,e_2]=e_1$. Let us lenote it by $L$. The question is how to describe all irreducible representations of $L$ (over complex numbers).
It means that we are to find all pairs of linear operators $A$ and $B$ in some vector space such that $AB-BA=A$, isn't it? I can give only one example: the adjoint representation $x\mapsto \mathrm{ad}\space x$.
Also I would like to note that I am to use as little techniques as possible.

Comment: The adjoint representation is not irreducible in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lie's theorem all irreducible representations of a complex solvable Lie algebra are $1$-dimensional. This is a well-known statement concerning Lie's theorem: Let  $\pi: \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ be a 
representation of a complex solvable Lie algebra on a
vector space $V$ . By Lie’s theorem there exists $v\in V$ such that for every 
$x\in \mathfrak{g}$ we have $\pi(x)(v)\in \mathbb{C}\cdot v$, so in particular 
$\mathbb{C}\cdot v$ is an invariant subspace of $V$.

Comment: As an additional note, the set of irreducible representations is parameterized by $\left(\mathfrak{g} / [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]\right)^{*}$, which in this case is 1 dimensional.